User logging in with Firebase can't log in and receives multiple internal errors, including "DUPLICATE_RAW_ID"
We have a Unity app and are using the Firebase (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk) for logging in. Occasionally we are seeing an error log when a user tries to log in that reads:
Firebase SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An internal error has occurred. [ DUPLICATE_RAW_ID ]) ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ DUPLICATE_RAW_ID ] at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync (Firebase.Auth.Credential credential) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ DUPLICATE_RAW_ID ] at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync (Firebase.Auth.Credential credential) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 <--- <>c__DisplayClass17_1:b__1(Task1) Firebase.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_11:b__1() Firebase.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1:b__0() Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:Wrap(Action) Firebase.Dispatcher:PollJobs() Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
I have no idea how to debug this and I don't see anything related to "DUPLICATE_RAW_ID" anywhere on the internet. Has anyone ever seen anything like this or have any idea of how to approach this? It seems relatively uncommon, but does occur a few times a day.

I think that this issue appear when called SignInWithCredentialAsync duplicatly.
Please review your authentication flow.

@PhilipJohn, have you seen that behavior before?

Yes, I saw similar issue.
